# How to transform a Custom Object List by excluding particular property in Kotlin?

Tags: collections, kotlin

How to transform a List into a new List by excluding a property in T. 
For instance if User data class has 10 properties, I need to transform List into a new List without one particular property in User . New List like List
    data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)

```
var userList = mutableListOf<User>()

var nameList= userList.map { it.name }
```

If a List to be created without property 'age'. Like

```
var withoutAgeList
```

Comment: If you need a list of strings then you've already created one via a `map` function

Comment: I want to exclude a property . For instance if User data class has 10 properties, I need to transform List<User> into a new List without one particular property in User . New List like List<UserWithoutAge>.

Comment: What do you mean by "excluding a property"? An instance will always point to all of its members, even if some are null. As other answers say, you either create another class or make this variable null. do you want to serialize this object? please clarify the use case you are trying to solve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example:

```
var userList = mutableListOf<User>()
var nameList= userList.map { it.name }
```

The question "What's the type of `nameList`?" has a simple answer: `List<String>`. So let me ask you a similar question: What's the type of `withoutAgeList`? The answer to that question informs the answer to *your* question.

Perhaps a user without the age property is a separate `AgelessUser` class, meaning `withoutAgeList` is of type `List<AgelessUser>`. In that case, I suggest either a constructor or a factory function that builds `AgelessUser` from `User`, and you want one of these:

```
val withoutAgeList =  userList.map { AgelessUser(it) } // constructor
val withoutAgeList =  userList.map { agelessUserOf(it) } // factory
```

Alternatively, maybe the `age` property in `User` is nullable and immutable, and you want to represent users without an age as a regular `User` where `age=null`. In this case, you could copy the Users and override the age field

```
// TODO: pass all the other fields too
val withoutAgeList =  userList.map { User(it.name, null) }
```

Assuming `Users` is a `data class`, we can avoid explicitly naming all fields by making use of `copy()`:

```
val withoutAgeList =  userList.map { it.copy(age = null) }
```

Maybe the age property is nullable and mutable — and you actually want to change the users in place instead of copying them. This is somewhat risky and I don't advocate doing it this way unless you *really* know what you're doing though.

```
userList.forEach { it.age = null } 
// They're actually the same list!
val withoutAgeList =  userList
```

Comment: good answer! In your last example, I suggest using `val withoutAgeList = userList.map { it.copy(age = null) }` in order to preserve inmutability

Comment: pdpi and crgarridos , this is what I was looking out for . Thank you .

Comment: @crgarridos What you describe would fit better in the second example. The third example was explicitly meant to be the "you actually want this to be mutable" case. Unusual, but certainly legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

In such a simple case you can map a list of Users into a list of strings:

```
val names: List<String> = userList.map(User::name)
```

Or you can declare a DTO and map into the latter:

```
class UserWithoutAge(val name: String)

val usersWithoutAge: List<UserWithoutAge> = userList.map { UserWithoutAge(it.name) }
```

P.S. you don't have to write an explicit type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Object Oriented approach:

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)

data class UserNoAge(var name: String) {
    constructor(user: User) : this(user.name)
}

var userList = listOf(User("John", 25), User("Jane", 30))
var userNoAge: List<UserNoAge> = mutableListOf<UserNoAge>()

userNoAge = userList.map{ UserNoAge(it) }

println(userNoAge) // [UserNoAge(name=John), UserNoAge(name=Jane)]
```